# Matlab - Edit text

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, handles

What I am trying to do is that when I put into "Edit text" (called: `funkcia_edit`) some function it will draw me graf to that function. Here is picture what I am trying to do, as you can see I have declared variables X and Y where Y is standing for `funkcia_edit` = `x.^2` and then I want to plot(x,y). Can any one help me how to make it work?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `ezplot`:

```
   ezplot(get(hObject,'String'));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're missing is the [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function in Matlab. If I'm not mistaken what you want to do is

```
y = eval(get(hObject,'String'));
```

Observe that while this is probably the easiest way of programming this functinality in MATLAB it is not necessary the safest. A user could write `system('rm -rf *')` and your program will evaluate that.